# How to update and delete duplicate in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

I have two table Add (Parent table) and AddXref (Child Table) and want to delete duplicate records in parent table and also update in Child table. In AddXref table the two records should have anyone of AddId from Add Table.i Tried with basic update statement but it didn't worked. How can I update AddXref Table?

My Attempt:
I have written the query up to this point, but am stuck on what to do next

```
Update AddXref name
SET a.AddId=b.AddId
FROM AddXref a
INNER JOIN Add b ON a.AddId = b.AddId
WHERE b.AddId = ( Select Top 1 ax.Addid from Add ax
                  INNER JOIN Add ax1  on
ax.AddressMain = a.AddressMain and
              ax.city = a.city and
              ax.Country = a.Country and
              ax.State = a.State and
              ax.ZipCode = a.ZipCode);

| AddId  | AddressMain  | City    | Country | State   | ZipCode    |
|--------|--------------|---------|---------|---------|------------|
| 8CA25D | 1234 Main St | Antioch | USA     | Florida | 60002-9714 |
| 5T7YTR | 1234 Main St | Antioch | USA     | Florida | 60002-9714 |

| AddXrefId | AddressId | IndividualId | InstitutionId |
|-----------|-----------|--------------|---------------|
| 822145    | 8CA25D    | 7652ER       | NULL          |
| 435902    | 5T7YTR    | NULL         | NA1043        |


| AddXrefId | AddressId | IndividualId | InstitutionId |
|-----------|-----------|--------------|---------------|
| 822145    | 8CA25D    | 7652ER       | NULL          |
| 435902    | 8CA25D    | NULL         | NA1043        | --Output either "8CA25D" or "5T7YTR" any one of it
```

Comment: This question is a bit unclear.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  What have you tried so far?  Are you trying to update the second table based on a match in the first?  Which fields?  Maybe give an example of the data before and after.  It's likely you wont be able to do everything with a single statement.

Comment: use group by to get min and max addid and update child first and then delete from parents.(assuming child will have FK and you only have 2 same records only)

Comment: @SteveShipway In the above case I have to delete any one of the record in "Add" table and record left in the Add Table should be update both records in AddXref.AddId column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first gather duplicate data.

```
select AddressMain, City, Country, State, ZipCode, min(addId) as minID, Max(addId) as MAxID
INTO #tmpData
from add
group by AddressMain, City, Country, State, ZipCode
```

second update child table

```
Update AddXref 
SET a.AddId=b.MaxID
FROM AddXref a
INNER JOIN #tmpData b ON a.AddId = b.MinID -- you can use maxId too if you want.
```

third remove duplicate record from parents.

```
DELETE FROM Add where AddId IN (Select MinID FROM #tmpData)
```

This code is not tested.

Comment: @ AJP The update statement is not working for some of the table where it has similar structure. Is there any other way to solve this issue?